# How do I align text inline with picture?

Tags: html, css

how do I align text under picture like this? [image]

Here is code:
https://jsfiddle.net/vzjj9eLy/

html:

```
<span class="test"> 
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a" alt="asd" width="316" height="316">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since 
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
    make a type specimen book. 
</span>
```

css:

```
.test{
  display:block;

}
.test img{
  display:block;
  position: relative;
    left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get you. Are you trying to alter the image using css?

Comment: Add to img `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: move text from span... then it will be on all width of parent element

Comment: I need text to align itself to the left of the picture. https://jsfiddle.net/vzjj9eLy/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

**HTML:**

```
<span class = "test">
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a" alt="asd" width="316" height="316">
    <span class="test_text">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since 
        the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
        make a type specimen book. 
    </span>
</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.test{
  width: 50%;
}
img{
  float: right;
}
.test.test_text{
  float: left;
}
```

You can see it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yrgomdxz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

easiest way i could think of , i used a table just to give you an idea , but you should use a div and set a margin to the left.

```
 <span class="test2"><img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&amp;a" alt="asd" width="316" height="316" /></span>
    <table width="510" height="100" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="63" height="96">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="437"><span class="test111">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since 
          the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
          make a type specimen book. </span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To align the text in left and then image you can create it using **div** element. 
Please find below the code i have attached css inline-

```
<div style="width:48%;float:left;vertical-align:bottom;margin:0px;">        
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since 
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
    make a type specimen book. 
</div>
<div style="width:50%;float:right;vertical-align:top;margin:0px;">
<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a" alt="asd" width="316" height="316">
</div>
```